# Convert Cordova Plugin to Flutter Plugin

Tags: java, cordova, flutter, cordova-plugins, flutter-plugin

I'm now converting my Android POS App to use Flutter Framework, my existing App was using Cordova Framework.

For this POS application, I used Cordova Bluetooth Printer Plugin to deal with a portable bluetooth printer as an output printer.

Now, I was trying to find Flutter Plugins that support bluetooth printer. But I didn't find one.

I was thinking to convert the Cordova plugin to Flutter plugin. I want to convert this plugin [cordova-plugin-datecs-printer](https://github.com/giorgiofellipe/cordova-plugin-datecs-printer)

Because, I didn't have much experience in Java.

My Questions, is it possible to convert the Cordova plugin by using the Java functional code that already made in the existing cordova plugin?

Can someone please help me to do it step by step or give me an overview to do the convertion.

Comment: Yeah it should be easy if you have the native code, you can use and paste the code, just will have to add some lines of code for the plugin. Check this resource: https://flutter.io/platform-channels/ , my concern is, the repo you have only has code for android, what about iOS? maybe you could build the app just in android native instead of flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has bluetooth printer plugins that you may want to try: [esc_pos_bluetooth](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_bluetooth) and [bluetooth_print](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_print).

As for converting Cordova plugins to Flutter, this is possible. But since you've mentioned that you have little experience working with platform-specific code i.e. Android, it might be more feasible to use existing Flutter plugins instead. It is possible though. Here's a [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) for developing packages and plugins for Flutter.